# Installation Issues on MacOS

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, directory, gopath, golang-migrate

I just came to know about Go and I installed it from here for MacOS, it went well but when I tried to setup my go workspace "https://golang.org/doc/install#macos" i followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qI8z_lB5Lw, But after setting my GOPATH it keeps giving me this error whenever i try to run anymore command related to go.

Error: go: **GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "Users/shahtajkhalid/Documents/go"**

There are solutions for this issue but all are for mostly for windows where a semicolon ar backslash is missing, but here the address is exactly same and I'm unable to continue further to testing it through this :https://golang.org/doc/install#testing.

Comment: `Users/shahtajkhalid/Documents/go` is a relative path. Absolute paths start with a `/`

Comment: JimB is right. A simple but often overlooked config.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but had the same issue. What worked for me was removing the quotes around the gopath. I understand it was said above, but it wasn't clear to me that the quotes were the issue. So the tutorial said

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/workspace/go"
```

and instead I did

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/workspace/go
```

This removed the error. It should be noted with GO 1.8 the [GOPATH is automatically set](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262), so probably not worth messing with.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **$HOME/Documents/go** in your GOPATH.

Comment: Weird but this did not work for me on my Mac. Did on my Fedora box though. <scratches head>

Comment: Where do you have your go directory in mac? I think It should be same as **/Users/<your username>/Documents/go**, otherwise you have to change **GOPATH**.